# C++ routine to delete data from database

Tags: googletest

Is there a mechanism in googletest framework that allows the test to clear the data even after a test fails (The code throws an exception and stops further execution (of clearing the data) if a test fails.

Thanks!

Comment: What test runner are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQLite operates from a single file, you can use `SetUp()` in a test fixture to copy a pre configured database file to where your program expects the database to be, overwriting the "runtime" database file with the pre configured one *before every test*.

That way every test gets a completely fresh database, initialized with all tables and possibly base data of your choice without running any database creation scripts. That should keep test runs speedy.

Comment: Thank you! I read that teardown() will be called after a test case completes execution. Will it be called even if a test case fails? or will it just continue to the next test?

Comment: @user1065969 As long as the test case doesn't crash the test runner, TearDown should be called. Problem is that if you cause memory corruption in your test, TearDown may also fail if you've overwritten the "wrong" memory :-/

Answer (score 2):

Run the tests on a temporary, [in-memory database](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: Thank you larsmans. But I am currently working on writing unit tests for sqlite database.

Comment: @user1065969: can you run the tests on an in-memory copy?